# How do I match the camera from Cinema4D into Blender?

Tags: camera, 3d-modeling, blender

I need to match the camera settings in Blender to the ones from a Cinema4D scene.

The main settings I need to apply to the Blender camera are:
Focal Length, Aperture Width and Field Of View.

I'm guessing FOV (Field Of View) will be lens, but I have no clue how to set the other settings or how they would map to the Blender camera.

I also had a look at the Python API and lens seems to be the main thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution: the K. G. Nyman's awesome [BLenses script](http://home.metrocast.net/~chipartist/BlensesSite/index.html).

I entered the apperture width from Cinema4D. I know image aspect ratio should be 16:9 (~ 1.77777778)
so I used that to calculate the apperture height. 
Then I pressed Calculate & Set Image A.R. and that returned the expected ratio. 
Lastly I pressed Calculate & Set FOV, which returned the exact FOV the Cinema4D camera had and that was it.